# Reducing the size of exported .eps files to the minimum necessary

Tags: graphics, export, eps-format

Running version 10.3 on my Power Mac with 22 Gbytes of memory I can create and export an .eps or .pdf graphics such as,

```
headandchest = Show[
   Entity["AnatomicalStructure", "Neck"]["Graphics3D"]];
Export["[my file path]\headandchest.eps", headandchest, "EPS"]
```

which I later use in a document.  However, the file size is rather large (~30 MByte).  If instead I merely click on the graphic output in my *Mathematica* session and **Save As...**, then the file size is rather small (~300 kByte), yet appears in full resolution in the final document.  This is the version I need.  Presumably there is a great deal of three-dimensional data in the original 3D graphics that is not copied when I copy directly from the *Mathematica* cell, rather than `Export` it.

(If your computer has less memory than mine, I suspect you can observe the same problem with a large, yet somewhat smaller, image file than mine.)

How can I `Export` the proper *small file-size* .eps or .pdf version of such a graphic?   (`Rasterize` and other methods to convert the image to a pixel-based formal are not acceptable.)

My problem has nothing whatsoever to do with the *speed* at which the files are written ([as answered elsewhere](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/80155/speeding-up-eps-exporting)), but instead with the *size* of the exported file.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Speeding up EPS exporting ?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/80155/speeding-up-eps-exporting)

Comment: @Edmund I don't think this is a duplicate of the question you linked to: the solution proposed there was to generate a rasterized version of the desired image, and David has already excluded any method involving rasterization as unacceptable to him in this case.

Comment: @David: I have also tried to use your code without success. It took quite a bit of time to even render the `headandchest` graphic, and the Export just hung my machine until I had to force quite *Mathematica*. I use v10.3 on Win7-64 with 8GB of RAM. How long did it take to generate the EPS file with `Export`, and how much memory do you have?

Comment: Not a duplicate.  See the original question, extended.

Comment: I think it a fair question why `save as` and `Export` produce such different results. Can you try to find a somewhat smaller example that shows the issue?

Comment: Smaller example in question.

Comment: On my system (Win7 x64 with MMa 10.3) `Export`ing of the `"Neck"` graphics to EPS produces a file of size 696 Mb while with `Save Selection As...` I was forced to kill *Mathematica* after 20 minutes of waiting. Tangentially related answer: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/38776/280

Answer (score 2):

What you actually need is to flatten your vector image. AFAIK there is no way to perform this operation in *Mathematica*. In [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/32948/280) I discuss known ways to do this using third-party software. Probably the most fast and simple solution would be to `Export` your image **in vectors** into PDF format using [Jen's workaround](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/87753/280) and then use Adobe Acrobat Pro for converting it into flattened **vector** EPS file as I describe in the [linked answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/32948/280).

I cannot check this solution myself because an attempt to `Export` your example figure into PDF kills my system with 8 Gb of physical memory.

Comment: Thanks.  We should suggest to *Wolfram Research* that they include the *flatten* option in exporting.  In the meantime I guess I'll simply copy and paste the large images, as described.